# mvn clean to delete test-output folder?

Tags: maven

I need to delete the `test-output` folder before every new build.

I have tried to use `mvn clean test`, but this does not delete the listed folder (visible below):

[image]

Any ideas how to delete the folder?

Comment: The `test-output` folder is created by running testng tests within Eclipse. The best thing is to configure the output folder for TestNG Tests to `target/test-output`. Windows->Preferences->TestNG->outputDirectory

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, what about if i execute the project via CMD?

Comment: Maven itself will not create such folder. This is only based on the usage of TestNG in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html ?